# Restrict ROW_NUMBER to order non-repeated values

Tags: sql, oracle, rank, row-number, dense-rank

How can I rank my data setting different values to each row, but giving the first values of the rank to the distinct rows?

I have emails data and I have to RANK the email as it is valid or not. I already did the validation part, however I'm having a lot of trouble with the ranking process.

This example of data is for one person.

```
ID     | EMAIL             |
181818 | example@mail.com  |
181818 | exam@pe@mail.com  |
181818 | example@mail.com  |
181818 |                   |
181818 | example1@mail.com |
181818 | examlpe@mail.com  |
181818 |                   |
```

So, my validation gets me something like this

```
ID     | EMAIL             | VALID
181818 | example@mail.com  |  1
181818 | exam@pe@mail.com  |  0
181818 | example@mail.com  |  1
181818 |                   |  0
181818 | example1@mail.com |  1
181818 | examlpe@mail.com  |  1
181818 |                   |  0
```

My code to rank this data is:

```
SELECT  E.ID,
        UPPER(E.EMAIL),
        ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (  PARTITION BY E.ID
                    ORDER BY (  CASE
                                  --VALIDATION PROCESS
                                 END) DESC) AS ROWNO
    FROM TABLE E
    WHERE E.ID = 181818 ;
```

This query returns the valid mails first and the invalid last, which is what I want, however I dont want repeated data to appear at top. I would like something like `DENSE_RANK` but the repeated data to be a at the end in order to avoid equal ranking values.

**RETURN:**

```
ID     | EMAIL             | ROWNO
181818 | example@mail.com  |  1
181818 | example@mail.com  |  2
181818 | example1@mail.com |  3
181818 | examlpe@mail.com  |  4
181818 | exam@pe@mail.com  |  5
181818 |                   |  6
181818 |                   |  7
```

**WANTED:**

```
ID     | EMAIL             | ROWNO
181818 | example@mail.com  |  1
181818 | example1@mail.com |  2
181818 | examlpe@mail.com  |  3
181818 | example@mail.com  |  4
181818 | exam@pe@mail.com  |  5
181818 |                   |  6
181818 |                   |  7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can enumerate the emails and then use that in the `ORDER BY`.  That will put the emails into groups, with all values appearing exactly once before duplicates.

```
SELECT E.ID, UPPER(E.EMAIL),
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.ID
                          ORDER BY is_valid DESC, seqnum
                         ) AS rownumber
FROM (SELECT E.*,
             (CASE --VALIDATION PROCESS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) a is_valid,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.ID, UPPER(e.EMAIL) ORDER BY e.id) as seqnum
      FROM TABLE E
     ) E
WHERE E.ID = 181818 ;
```

Comment: I have to read a little more to understand how this functions, but for 2 examples is working fine. Thanks a lot for the quick answer.